# Swap pointers instead of memcpy

Tags: c, optimization, pointers, swap, memcpy

**EDIT**: I'm sorry for my mistakes in my code snippets, now I see both outputs were same. Below is an edited version.

Let's say I have a structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    char m[5];
    char f[6];
} COUPLE;
```

And a file containing just phrase `RomeoJuliet` that I read into an array:

```
char *data = malloc(11);
FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "rb");
fread(data, 1, 11, f);
fclose(f);
```

I always use this code when I need to fill my structure from a byte array:

```
COUPLE titanic;
memcpy(&titanic, data, sizeof(data));
printf("%s and %s", titanic.m, titanic.f);
```

This works fine, but really my byte array can be very big, so below is my attempt to optimize my code.

```
COUPLE *titanic = (COUPLE *)data;
printf("%s and %s", titanic->m, titanic->f);
```

So, my questions are:

1. (obsolete) Why do I get different outputs?
2. (obsolete) How can I fill a structure just by casting from an array?
3. Should I avoid this kind of optimization?
4. Are there possible pitfalls in it?

Comment: re #3: Yes, by all means.

Comment: Hint Re #1: Think about how C-style strings are terminated.

Comment: Whatever makes you think this is any kind of "optimization" ? It's just appallingly bad programming with no obvious benefit to justify it.

Comment: Really? Why does (s)he get different outputs for an identical memory representation? Neither is zero-terminated.

Comment: Re #2: to initialise struct variables, you really should be using the struct initialisation syntax, in this case `COUPLE titanic = { "Romeo", "Juliet" }` (minus the problem in your struct that @In silico hinted at). You may be able to define a `union` for your purposes, but I agree with @sbi - I suspect you're trying to solve a non-problem. I also doubt very much that your first example works as you say it does.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer: The character string "RomeoJuliet" is null-terminated, so there's actually twelve characters, not eleven. Not to mention that the individual character arrays in `COUPLE` are not big enough to properly store "Romeo" and "Juliet" respectively.

Comment: This is great question actually. Why no upvotes?

Comment: What kind of compiler are you using? In VC2008 both methods produce the same output. I can't decide which one is worst. Both doesn't work as expected but additionally first one during memcpy corrupt stack, because you copy 12 byte (sizeof(data)) into 11 bytes long structure.

Comment: @sbi, Thank you, but don't you mind explaining it? @In silico, thank you for the hint. @Paul R, I think swapping the pointers works faster than copying a big piece of data. @pmjordan, actually the data is read from the file, so I cannot use that syntax. Thank you for the `union` hint. @Zuljin, I'm using GCC, but considering to move to VC2010. Thank you for mentioning about the stack corruption.

Comment: @In silico: "Romeo", however, is not null-terminated. I wouldn't expect the first output (where "%s and %s" was used) to print "Romeo and Juliet" -- I would expect "RomeoJuliet and Juliet" (I mean, assuming the null-termination from before, which is actually a buffer overflow and shouldn't be assumed…).

Comment: @Conrad Meyer: I'm not sure how the OP got that to work either, I just got a stack corruption error when I ran the code with a debugger. The problem is still with the fact that in both of the OP's code snippets the individual members of `COUPLE` won't be properly null-terminated.

Comment: @Angel: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  made my comment to your question, I didn't have the time to elaborate, so here's an attempt to answer. The code has changed since, and I'm not sure I would add that comment to the code as it is now.

Nevertheless, the underlying reason that made me add that comment still stands: ***Unless you measured*** and found that the code in question does indeed have a significant negative impact on performance, ***don't attempt to optimize***. Instead, strive to make your code ***as readable as possible***.

I seriously doubt that copying the data in memory will have a significant performance impact after copying them from the disk into memory. However, since your code as provided makes assumptions about the struct's layout in memory anyway, directly reading into the struct wouldn't really make the code less readable (or less vulnerable to changes to that layout):

```
COUPLE titanic;
FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "rb");
fread(&titanic, sizeof(titanic), 1, f);
```

Or, if you indeed have an array, read into the array directly:

```
COUPLE titanic[SIZE];
FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "rb");
fread(&titanic, sizeof(titanic), SIZE, f);
```

Depending on `SIZE`, the latter could indeed make a potentially huge difference in performance. Accessing the disk for bigger chunks is, in general, faster that doing it for smaller chunks. (Although disk caching might alleviate that.)

Comment: Hell yeah, I forgot I can fill the structure directly from the file. Thank you so much for pointing me at this, and for the suggestion not to optimize when it's not needed. But what's the point of `memcpy` in both your examples?

Comment: @Angel: The point of `memcpy()` in my examples is to remind you that cut&paste programming does hav its downsides. For example, you might leave in pointless code...

Comment: I see :D Finally, I think my question has an answer, so thank you and everyone who discussed this here.

Comment: @Angel: You would have to thank karlphillip for that answer, because [he posted a link to it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=515959#515959) in the chat, making me aware that it was still unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

What your are saying is not true. You method if filling a struct from a string my using `memcpy` will not and does not work. Firstly, when you do

```
memcpy(&titanic, data, sizeof(data));
```

you are copying 12 bytes from the char array. Meanwhile, the struct is not guaranteed to be 12 bytes large (the total size is only 11), so it will cause memory overrun in general case.

Secondly, the char array in `titanic.m` will not be zero terminated. The same is true for `titanic.f`, which is why your `printf` has absolutely no change of outputing `"Romeo and Juliet"`, as you falsely claim.

You claim that your first example "works fine" (why?), while in reality the first example does not work at all, and even when it "works" it suffers from the very similar problems to your second example (although in general case the exact problems will not be predictable).

The approach you are trying to use is not viable. You can't produce a correctly formed struct with two strings in it from one original string. One obvious reason why it can't be done is that for two strings you need two zero-terminators, while your original string has only one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just simplified my real structure, because it was too big for posting here. The data for filling the structure is read from the file, and there're no zeroes terminating the strings. I'll edit my first post. Thank you.

Comment: If you are saying that these strings aren't zero terminated in file then how length of these strings is stored in file?

Answer (score 1):

1. Because it's the members start at a different position. Printf() print a null (\0) terminated sentence.
2. You can do it like that. But you need to pay attention to the types and how to use them.
3. It can be good if you know what you're doing.
4. Lot's of pitfalls if you don't know what you're doing... There's no type safety.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only solution that doesn't involves memcpy would be solution that directly read from file to structure. This could be something like this

```
typedef struct
{
    char m[6];
    char f[7];
} COUPLE;

COUPLE titanic;

FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "rb");
fread(titanic.m, 1, 5, f);
titanic.m[5] = '\0';
fread(titanic.f, 1, 6, f);
titanic.f[6] = '\0';
fclose(f);

printf("%s and %s", titanic.m, titanic.f);
```

Of course this example probably is not optimal, because I think that one call of fread and few memcpy would be faster than 2 freads. That way or another both solutions are very unrealistic, because the problem is unrealistic - who needs structure that stores 5 and 6 character length name.

Comment: Yes, this is not the real structure, I have six structures, and one main that includes arrays of those structures (it's actually the file content).Thank you very much, I think I'll stick with sbi's advice to read the structures directly from the file.